# How to use 480s * [1,2,3,4,5,6] to get multiple instant vectors?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a rate query:

```
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset 480s)
```

How do I turn this into a query that returns multiple vectors with multiples of the offset?

eg

```
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (480 * 1)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (480 * 2)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (480 * 3)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (480 * 4)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (480 * 5)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (480 * 6)s)
```

or better yet:

```
x = 480
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * 1)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * 2)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * 3)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * 4)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * 5)s)
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * 6)s)
```

or even better still:

```
x = 480
hs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
rate(foo_meter[1m] offset (x * hs)s)
```

Comment: what are you using to query prometheus? Grafana, the rest API directly in a script, ...?

Comment: @JensBaitinger Grafana